# how to write code of this diagram like photo below :

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

I'm a beginner on this, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a starting point and only left picture.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
 reddot/.style={draw, fill,circle, minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,color=red},
 graydot/.style={draw, fill,circle, minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,color=gray},
 blackdot/.style={draw, fill,circle, minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt,color=black},
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
\node at (\x,0) [reddot] (\x) {};}
\node at (0.5,0.5) [blackdot] (3) {};
\node at (1.5,0.5) [graydot] (4) {};
\node at (0.5,-0.5) [graydot] (5) {};
\node at (1.5,-0.5) [blackdot] (6) {};
\node at (1,1) [reddot] (7) {};
\node at (1,-1) [reddot] (8) {};
\draw (0,1)--(3)--(4)--(2,1);
\draw (0,-1)--(5)--(6)--(2,-1);
\draw (3)--(5) (4)--(6);
\draw [red,->](7)--(1);
\draw [red,->](8)--(1);
\draw [red,->](1)--(0);
\draw [red,->](1)--(2);
\draw[red,,->] (2) arc[radius=1, start angle=0, end angle= 90];
\draw[red,,->] (0) arc[radius=1, start angle=180, end angle= 270];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i need two pictures in the same line

Comment: For second picture, change only the location of the black and gray dots and arcs. You can place the two pictures side by side. For this, search on TeX.SE!